# Translation discreteness of pseudo-Anosov elements

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-groups

Consider the action of mapping class groups on the curve graphs. A pseudo-Anosov element  $g$ acts by a loxodromic isometry on the hyperbolic curve graphs. The translation length of $g$ is the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{d(o, g^no)}{n}$, where $o$ is a fixed point in the curve graph.

It is clear that the translation length remains the same under conjugacy. The question I want to ask is the following:

whether there are only finitely many conjugacy classes of pseudo-Anosov elements with translation length less than a fixed constant?

It appears to me the answer is yes, but I do not know where I can find a reference.

[**Edits**]
**The above question has a negative answer, pointed out by Ian Agol in a comment.**

Comment: This is false, there will be infinitely many distinct mapping classes with bounded translation length. Take a pseudo-Anosov, and compose it with powers of a Dehn twist. These will give infinitely many distinct pseudo-Anosovs with bounded translation length.

Comment: @IanAgol You are right! Thanks for providing this example.